# Vue: method called from mounted() is not executed because 'is not a function'

Tags: vue.js

See this snippet

```
mmethods: {
    getCustomers: function(page = 1) {
       ....
    }
},
mounted() {
    // Fetch initial results
    this.getCustomers();
}
```

My problem is that error

> Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.getCustomers is not a function"

Why?

Comment: `mmethods:` instead of `methods:`?

Comment: OMG !!!! Fixed .. sorry. appen an answer and i'll upvote and approve. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `methods` and not `mmethods`, just a typo